# Maven: Could not find artifact javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.4 in central

Tags: java, maven

I want to add `jsp-api 2.4` as a dependency to my project. So I add the following code to my `pom.xml` as described on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.4)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But I keep getting the following error on `mvn package`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sefs: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project ru.jofsey:sefs:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.4 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that version 2.4 is not in central, but is in the "jboss 3rd-party" repository.  If you add configuration for this repo, it should work.  There are a few ways to do this, depending for example whether you're using a repo manager.  You could specify it in your settings.xml, or in the pom.xml for the project you're building.

When using mvnrepository.com be sure to pay attention to the **Repositories** field in the table above the tabs that show the pom markup.

Comment: Hm. But there is maven central in "repositories" field. https://cloclo22.datacloudmail.ru/weblink/view/MUxA/TBjaaEC16?etag=7DE44C776C08865B09E9E6E071246BC4C93578E8&key=067ab40e7ead6605bb4854499861dc9ded323539

Comment: I don't know what that is you're looking at, but cloclo22.datacloudmail.ru is not mvnrepository.com and I don't click unknown links from stackoverflow comments.  The mvnrepository link would be https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/sun-servlet/jsp-api/2.4 which shows the repo info as I noted above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the newest JSP version that can be found in Maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But what is wrong with `2.4`? mvnrepository.com shows it exists in Maven central. Can't I rely on mvnrepository.com?

Comment: I've never had trouble relying on mvnrepository.com, but see my answer for a little gotcha...

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api as it can be seen here, version 2.4 does not exist. Probably, 2.4 is the version of servlet-api, but not jsp-api artifact.